# Can one low variable be used across multiple sites (using MSM)

Tags: low-variables

Can 1 low variable be created and used across multiple sites. Or would you have to copy the instance for each site?

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you will have to use [the Parse tag](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables/docs/tags#parse-tag) or one of its aliases:

```
{exp:low_variables:single var="my_site:my_var"}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe so. I think you'll have to create a new one on each site.

Comment: Are you able to confirm this?